# Radicals/rational roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the smallest positive integer $a,$ greater than 1000, such that the equation
$$\sqrt{a - \sqrt{a + x}} = x$$ has a rational root.

Can someone help me with this? I'm thinking of squaring it but is that the correct way to approach this?

Comment: Unless you try it, you will never find out.

Answer (score 3):

Let's square it twice to see what happens. We get
$$
(a-x^2)^2=a+x
$$
Surprisingly, this [factors](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor(a-x%5E2)%5E2-(a%2Bx)) as
$$
(a - x^2 - x - 1) (a - x^2 + x)=0
$$
and so the only possible values of $a$ are
$$
a =x^2+x+1,
\quad
a=x^2-x
$$
Since $a$ is an integer, so must be $x$, because $x$ is a rational algebraic integer.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: The factorisation: $$(a-x^2)^2=a+x\\(a-x^2)^2-x^2=a+x-x^2\\(a-x^2-x)(a-x^2+x)-(a+x-x^2)=0\\(a-x-x^2-1)(a+x-x^2)=0$$

Comment: `sage: [ (k, k^2+k+1) for k in [30..35] ]`

gives

`[(30, 931), (31, 993), (32, 1057), (33, 1123), (34, 1191), (35, 1261)]`

and

`sage: [ (k, k^2-k) for k in [30..35] ]`

gives

`[(30, 870), (31, 930), (32, 992), (33, 1056), (34, 1122), (35, 1190)]`

Answer (score 1):

How is the factorization from lhf derived?  Let's take a closer look.

After you get the equation given by lhf

$(a-x^2)^2=a+x$

expand and collect terms with like powers of $a$ to get

$a^2-(2x^2+1)a+(x^4-x)=0$

If this is to be solved by an integer value of $a$, then the discriminant

$(2x^2+1)^2-4(x^4-x)=4x^2+4x+1$

must be a perfect square.  But, it actually equals $(2x+1)^2$ for *all* $x$. Taking advantage, solve for $a$ in terms of $x$ with the quadratic formula to get

$a=((2x^2+1)\pm(2x+1))/2\in\{x^2+x+1,x^2-x\}$

which are lhf's claimed roots.